# Self Join Table in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Suppose I have a table resulted from a query like this:

```
+-------+-----+--------------------+-----+--------------------+
|CODE   |CURR |FRONT-END CHARGE    |CCY  |BACK-END CHARGE     |
+-------+-----+--------------------+-----+--------------------+
|002    |AUD  |5.25                |PHP  | 3.75               |
|002    |AUD  |1.75                |USD  | 1.25               |
|002    |BGN  |  14                |PHP  | 8.75               |
|002    |BGN  |   6                |USD  | 3.75               |
|002    |BND  | 9.5                |PHP  |  8.5               |
|002    |BND  |4.25                |USD  |12.75               |
|002    |CAD  |12.5                |USD  | 6.75               |
|002    |INR  |  35                |PHP  |22.75               |
|002    |INR  |  25                |USD  |16.25               |
|002    |YEN  |55.5                |PHP  |16.55               |
|002    |YEN  |77.5                |USD  | 39.2               |
+-------+-----+--------------------+-----+--------------------+
```

But I want to have a result like this:

```
+-------+-----+--------------------+-----+--------------------+
|CODE   |CURR |FRONT-END CHARGE    |CCY  |BACK-END CHARGE     |
+-------+-----+--------------------+-----+--------------------+
|002    |AUD  |7                   |PHP  | 3.75               |
|002    |     |                    |USD  | 1.25               |
|002    |BGN  |20                  |PHP  | 8.75               |
|002    |     |                    |USD  | 3.75               |
|002    |BND  |13.75               |PHP  |  8.5               |
|002    |     |                    |USD  |12.75               |
|002    |CAD  |12.5                |USD  | 6.75               |
|002    |INR  |60                  |PHP  |22.75               |
|002    |     |                    |USD  |16.25               |
|002    |YEN  |133                 |PHP  |16.55               |
|002    |     |                    |USD  | 39.2               |
+-------+-----+--------------------+-----+--------------------+
```

Note that the Front-end charge is the sum of every charges on each of the currency.

I tried using coalesce but it returns the same table when selecting. I also tried self join but the sum on each of the charges becomes different. This is in oracle 11g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of transformation should usually be done in the presentation layer -- because the results are not really a SQL table:  rows are missing column values.

But, you can do this using window functions:

```
select code,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by code, curr order by front_end_charge desc) = 1
             then code
        end) as code,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by code, curr order by front_end_charge desc) = 1
             then sum(front_end_charge) over (partition by code, curr)
        end) as front_end_charge,
       ccy, back_end_charge
from t
order by t.code, t.curr, t.front_end_charge desc;
```

It is important that the outer `order by` match the `order by` in the `row_number()` expressions.  SQL queries only return results in a determined order when `order by` is present.